# Chef - get variable from ruby block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I try to get a variable from my ruby block, but Chef doesn't recognise my variable outside of this block. How can I retrieve any variable out of ruby block? Thanks in advance.

```
ruby_block 'fetch_path' do                                                                            
    block do                                                                                          
         current_path =  `sudo cat /var/chef/cache/revision`                          
         new_path = current_path.to_s.split(',').last.split('"').drop(1).first     
         Chef::Log.info("### Your Current Directory: '#{new_path}' ###")           
    end                                                                                               
 end                                                                                                   

 Chef::Log.info("### Your Current Directory: '#{new_path}' ###")
```

Within the block I can get a value, but, out of block - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two thing here.

First, your second `Chef::Log.info` will be run at compilation phase, at this time your `ruby_block` has not been converged. See [here about it](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#run-in-compile-phase). You can prefix your logs with 1) and 2) to witch one runs first.

Second, there's a scoping problem, when you define a variable in a block, it is available only within this block.

In chef you can use `node.run_state['variable']` as a global variable usable in all recipes, without an use case it's hard to showcase this.

Side note: you should not use the backticks ``` `` ``` construction to execute commands and prefer using [shell_out](https://docs.chef.io/release/12-13/dsl_recipe.html#shell-out) from the recipe DSL.